# Selenium C# Can't find ID or Title

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I manage to open a firefox browser, go to http://www.google.com/ search for "Bath Fitter". When i see a bunch of links, i want to in fact click on an item of the top menu provided by Google, Images. Images is located next to Map Videos News...
How can i have it click on Images?

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;   
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace SeleniumHelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = null;
            try
            {
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

                IWebElement searchInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq"));
                searchInput.SendKeys("Bath Fitter");
                searchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

                searchInput.FindElement(By.Name("Images"));
                searchInput.Click();
                driver.Close();

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception ****" + e.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel stupid now to not to find the bug at first place. The way you are trying to pass click is not right. Now that I took a look again found it. I edited your code and try that

Answer (score 1):

More specifically you can also write your selector pointing from Top Navigation. This is the XPath.

```
.//*[@id='hdtb_msb']//a[.='Images']
```

try this;

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='hdtb_msb']//a[.='Images']"));
```

**EDIT:**
Even though the selectors above were correct your code was not working because of the second page was taking too long to load. There you need to wait for the the element to be in ready state and an *implicit* wait is needed. Change the code in your try block and replace with mine and try

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

IWebElement searchInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq"));
searchInput.SendKeys("Bath Fitter");
searchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

//this is the magic
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
By byImage = By.XPath(".//*[@id='top_nav']//a[.='Images']");
IWebElement imagElement =
                    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(byImage));
imagElement.Click();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65296/discussion-on-answer-by-saifur-selenium-c-cant-find-id-or-title).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks. I tried to move this to chat but couldn't since Nicolas Touma doesn't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
links.First(element => element.Text == "Images").Click();
```